# What is 'self' that shows up in android trace view

Tags: android, debugging, trace

I've started to use the android Trace view tool to profile my game.  In some of my methods im seeing a large percentage of time taken up in 'self'.

I have a feeling its something obvious but does anyone know what this represents?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Self` is time spent in the actual method, instead of children. For example, if you have a method that runs a loop doing some math, and then calling some draw functions, you'll see the time listed for the draw functions in `children`, and the time spent in that method itself(mainly the math loop) as `self`.

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense